# Woocommerce payment gateway integration custom

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Is it possible to integrate fonepaisa payment integration with wordpress? If yes, what are the steps that I need to follow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you want to integrate to exactly? WooCommerce? Gravity Forms? Easy Digital Downloads?

Comment: Woocommerce during checkout page

Answer (score 0):

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-other-payment-gateway/screenshots/
```

Add any custom Payemnt gateway to woo commerce using this plugin.

Comment: I looked into this, but only the comments can be added but no integration can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Fonepaisa seems to have a plugin available on their website. See the following URL: https://www.fonepaisa.com/developer

Plugins -> C. WooCommerce (Wordpress)

Comment: Hey Marinus,

I'm currently using the plugin for now but my client already has an asp .net web app for booking and he wants the website to be linked to that application. The web app is hosted on IIS8 server and the wordpress runs on PHP5. I was wondering how how this can be implemented.

Do let me know if you find any solution.

Thanks in advance!!